# How do I add a line graph from another dataset to an existing line graph where facet grid has been used?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am plotting a graph in `RStudio` using `ggplot2`. My `R` codes for the plot stand as follows:

```
g1 <- ggplot(mydata1, aes(x=month(date), y=rn)) + 
      geom_line() +
      geom_point(color="red", size=3) +
      geom_smooth(se=FALSE) +
      facet_grid(market ~ year(date))

g1 + theme_solarized() +
     scale_colour_solarized("blue")
```

The above codes give the following output:

[image: plot1]

I need to add another line graph into the above plot and the data will come from another dataset (let's call it mydata2), which is in the same format structure as `mydata1`. This second line graph won't need to have the smoothed line as in the existing graph. However. I will need the line graph to be of a different color than the existing line graph.

Here is how `mydata2` looks:

```
> head(mydata2)

     date    rn   market
1 1/1/2015  100    OTA
2 2/1/2015  127    OTA
3 3/1/2015  100    OTA
4 4/1/2015  100    OTA
5 5/1/2015   89    OTA
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks. Please post as answer and I will give my vote accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `mydata2` as the `data=` argument in a separate `geom_line()` call:

```
+ geom_line(data = mydata2, aes(x = month(date) , y = rn))
```